# Disabling FirebaseMessagingService programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase for receiving push notifications. My problem is that i want to  make an option for users available, where they can disable these Notifications.

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:icon="@drawable/ico_myapp_application">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- END Manual Firebase Additions -->
</application>
```

Is there a way to prevent the app from register/creating the `FirebaseMessagingService`?

Comment: What if you make options for users to Unsubscribe from your Firebase topic, they would stop getting the notifications. Unless if you are sending it directly to their ID

Comment: Easiest solution i have not considered. Thanks!

Comment: @HtmlTosin You should add that in as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make options for users to Unsubscribe from your Firebase topic, they would stop getting the notifications. Unless if you are sending it directly to their ID.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

and then unsubscribe users

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news");
```